# Cannot post paremeters with jQuery and Kohana php framework

Tags: php, jquery, post, kohana-3

I'm trying to do a simple test post with jQuery in Kohana. Note that it works fine when I don't include any parameters. But when I do, it stops working. Here's the jQuery post:

```
        var url = "home/order";
        $.post(url, { name: name}, function(data) {
                 alert('test');
        });
```

And here's the action method (never mind what it does, that's just nonsense, and I'm actually not using the parameter at all for this test, I just want it to return to show the alert for now so I see it works, but keep in mind that it works when I have no parameters):

```
public function action_order($name)
{
    $view = new View('home/index');
    $head = new View('home/head');
    $this->template->head = $head;
    $this->template->content = "TEST";
}
```

In the end I actually want two parameters here, but keeping it simple for now to try to get it to work at all.

So why doesn't this work? I've been doing this sort of thing in Asp.Net MVC all the time. Does it have something to do with routing? I have only the default route set up. Do I need to add something for it to be able to take parameters other than ones named "id"??

I never had to do anything like that in Asp.Net MVC, so it doesn't seem like it to me, but maybe that's different here, I don't know...

Or am I not passing the parameters or receiving them the correct way for Kohana?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All data passed to jQuery `$.post` method will go to `Request::post()` method. To access this data in your controller, use `$this->request->post()`.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll look into that. I also eventually found that you could use $this->request->param('name', FALSE); too... But if you don't mind, another simple question: how do I return a value? I tried $this->request->response = "TEST"; but that didn't work. All I want is to return a string so that I can alert the data callback parameter... in Asp.Net MVC I would simply say "return "TEST";" What is the equivalent here?

Comment: $this->request->param('name') requires url to be /controller/action/name. You need to have a different routing for this (since you use the default route, which takes id after action not name). I suggest you have a detailed look into the docs - http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/routing. In Kohana routing works quite differently then in ASP.NET MVC and without good understanding you'll run into problems all the time. In Kohana you don't return a value, you rather pass it to the view. You could do $this->template->content = 'TEST' if you use a template controller.

Comment: Ok, thank you, but I tried that, and that strangely only works if I also fill the other parts of the template ($head and so on), meaning I get a whole view returned. This could be useful in some cases, but is there really no way to just return a value? If I do as you suggested it only seems to serve an entire view, and I often need only a value to alert in an alert box or something, or possiblyjjust load content into a single div without loading an entire view?

Comment: try $this->response->body('TEST')

Comment: Thanks, that worked! So I guess body() doesn't have anything to do with the html body element then, or what? Couldn't find it documented in the Kohana docs.

Comment: Exactly - body($content) will output pure $content